# how to reduce chace on android application (using eclipse)?

Tags: android, eclipse, image, caching

I'm developing application for my android tablet that using many images.
in my activity, I use effect splash that show image (3840 x 2108 70 KB) for the opening theme.
I use another background image (3840 x 2108 69 KB).
but, when I test it on my tablet, this application's cache reached 80 MB!
For your information, I load the image from my xml file.
Can anyone help me to reduce it?
Is it wrong to load image from xml file?
Is it the size of my images that cause this problem?

//UPDATE
at the end, i didn't found a really good way to my question. I'm using xml (I put at dawable) file to replace my big size image, and this method really reduce the cache alot. My conclusion is avoid using big image, instead, just replace the color image using color.

The advantage to use color is "faste to load", it reduce lag of my application.

Comment: have you enabled progruard in your apk?  
(if you do not know what it is please let me know)

Comment: which folder do you put the images?

Comment: @noobProgrammer I did some research on proguard, and i think proguard is used for remove any unused code right? so my unused image will be delete and reduce my cache? am i right?

Answer (score 0):

Android default color model is ARGB_8888. It takes 4 byte for 1 pixel. So splash and background bitmap images in memory takes 3840*2108*4*2 = 61.76MB. You could resize the images for different device dpi and put them in proper drawable folder. For example, drawable-hdpi is suitable for 240 dpi, drawable-xxhdpi is suitable for 480 dpi.

In addition, you could manually load the images with java code. The following is a method to resolve the image safely:

```
protected Bitmap getBitmapSafely(Resources res, int id, int sampleSize) {
// res = youractivity.getResources, id = R.drawable.yourimageid
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inPurgeable = true;
    options.inSampleSize = sampleSize;
    try {
          bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res,
                      id, options);
    } catch (OutOfMemoryError oom) {
        Log.w("ImageView", "OOM with sampleSize " + sampleSize, oom);
        System.gc();
        bitmap = getBitmapSafely(res, id, sampleSize + 1);
    }

    return bitmap;
}
```

Your could use this method with sampleSize = 1 at first time. If there is not enough memory, it will catch OOM and increase the sampleSize until the image can be resolved.

Comment: i put my image on res/drawable-xhdpi...so how can I call my image?
can you give an example to use this function?
is this code will give me aonther error about out of memory problem? because some of my friend get out of memory problem because of using method like this...

Comment: sorry, i get the other problem, i cannot load the result bitmap image on my relative layout as my background?